# Replacing copper water line to refrigerator water/ice

Tags: water, leak, refrigerator, replacement

The water line comes through the cabinet behind the refrigerator. It immediately has a connection to copper tubing. The copper tubing is excessive and is wound around in no certain way and ends up connecting to the clear tubing coming out of the refrigerator with a connector. The copper  line got bent and a hole is now spewing water. What can i replace the copper tubing with?

Comment: Cut the copper shorter than the leak and connect there.  Add a coupling where the leak is.  A picture of the tubing showing where the leak is will help with the proper answer.

Comment: Can I use clear tubing or braided hose?

Comment: Can use any tubing/hose you trust not to burst.  Most plumbing is not my way is the only right way allowed, but what works and is trusted.  Garden hoses are low on the list of trust plumbing under constant pressure to use.

Comment: You’ll find fridge water supply kits with plastic hose at the big box stores. Plastic > copper, in my opinion.

Comment: I can't get the image to upload. Says it's to big. the place it's leaking from is right in the middle of the copper tubing. So I can cut on each side of the leak and connect it with a coupling?

Comment: OK. I'll get a kit.  I looked at them and I understand now.  Thank you to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> What can i replace the copper tubing with?

More copper tubing, plastic tubing, braided flex, or eliminate it altogether. Most times that you see copper tubing coiled up behind a refrigerator is to facilitate easily pulling the fridge out to access the rear area without pulling on the icemaker supply. Cut the copper tube and join to:

- another section of copper tube
- a section of poly tube
- a braided supply line

compression coupler/union:

[image]

All of these options require use of a proper connector/coupler fitting and the appropriate details for that fitting and the tubing type. Poly tube compression fittings should have a plastic ferrule and a brass tube insert; copper a brass ferrule, braided hose needs likely nothing.